# How to make passport pictures using only open-source or free software?

Tags: printing, open-source, images

I have found [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20110719063908/http://sitemason.vanderbilt.edu/files/eLdE8E/Photoshop%20Passport%20Template%20Instructions.pdf) which do what I want, unfortunately it requires expensive Photoshop software.

Basically, I need to plaster the same picture 6 times on an image, so that after sending it to Walgreens for printing I can take the 4x6 and cut it up into six 2x2 pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread is a bit older but in case someone has a similar problem. On GitHub there is an offline tool that solves exactly this problem.
Note: The website must be hosted on a web server, but the server can also run locally.

GitHub project: https://github.com/safijari/passport_photo_maker

Answer (score 1):

[GIMP](https://www.gimp.org) is the most robust open-source raster image editor I know of, and it can definitely do what you've described.